# How to build custom pagination with center pages

Tags: pagination

How to build custom pagination in WordPress, which display center pages.
For example if there is 100 pagination pages, pagination should look like this -
for active page 1:

**1**  2  3  49  50  51  98  99  100

Comment: Center or middle page numbers from where? For example, if the active page is 1, then middle of 1 to 100 is 50. So it can show `1 2 3 49 50 51 98 99 100`. But what if the active page is 20, or 30 or 60? What will be shown then? You need to provide more details before someone can answer this.

Comment: I thought about it and the best solution is the logarithm between the current location and the endpoint of pagination. Please help, thank you.

Comment: I need a soultion. I have a WordPress site which has 4 blog list pages, each with more than 600 pagination pages. I would like to have more links to pages in pagination. Please tell me, how change pagination - how to let users get to far pagination pages?

Comment: IMHO, for you the best solution would be to use a pagination plugin. For example: [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/alphabetic-pagination/) or [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/). They may have options you're looking for.